# How to efficiently filter and select attributes based on conditional formatting?

Tags: expression, filter, definition-query, rule-based, conditional

I am wishing to filter my attribute table to display only certain values that meet certain criteria based on multiple column values.

For example, I want to show all locations on my map that are `Lost shark` from my `Scientificname` column and also including strings from a `FishNotes` column and at the same time remove locations using `Yes` values from my `spatial_analysis_remove` column.

I have been attempting this in the `Query Builder` within the layer properties using statements like below, I have been able to select values but not remove values:

[image: filter expression]

```
"Scientificname" IN ('Lost Shark', 'Other species') OR
"Fish_Use" IN ('Eaten by shark', 'Released') AND
"FishNotes"  IN ('Silvertip shark', 'Blacktip reef shark') AND 
"spatial_analysis_remove" != 'Yes'
```

I am looking for a clean method rather than a dirty way i.e. selecting values manually then deleting them from my attribute table (this is not what I want to do). Ideally looking for a nice expression that I can save and is editable and either apply to the attribute table or rule-based symbology.

Should I be using the `Expression String Builder` and `expression CASE` within the layer symbology? How would I go about using the conditional case arguments?

I will need to do a number of these queries to display different locations on a map based on differing column values.

Photo of my attribute table:

[image]

Comment: So, are you asking, how to filter/select features, or how to remove them, how to get your expression to work, or something different? While the question is very detailled, it still is a bit unclear, what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: This probably should have been multiple questions so I apologise. Essentially 1. How do I get the expression to work & 2. should I be using the Expression String Builder or Query Builder? I want to select features but I'm having trouble where I can select `Lost Shark` but some also have a `Yes` value in the `spatial_analysis_remove` column, therefore I don't want them displayed. I do not want to remove them completely, just not show them on the map display.

Comment: Since question 2 seems a bit unclear to yourself: Where do you plan to use this expression? In the `select by expression` dialogue, for `categorized` symbology, or something different?

Comment: When mixing `AND` and `OR`, it is safer to add parentheses around what should be considered for the `or` and the `and` (`(A AND B) OR (C AND D)` vs `A AND (B OR C) AND D` etc). While there is a rule of precedence, it is not necessarily obvious

Comment: @JGH will this work even if in the last argument I'm trying to remove values that would have been selected in the first part of the expression.

Comment: @Erik I originally was attempting in Feature Filter of the properties dialogue box. But then I will need to create new layers to provide other expressions and I guess this is the same if I were to choose select by expression in the attribute table. At the minute I have been flipping back between print composer and changing the Feature Filter to display different values and I have a feeling this is quite cumbersome. So would filtering by expression in rule-based symbology be a better option?